# triggered breakpoint when trying to deallocate and recreate array dynamically

Tags: c++

so the purpose of this code is to delete an array in order to resize it by 1 because I want to add another object to it. The issue is it triggeres a breakpoint when I delete the array.

```
Car& Car::operator+=(Engine e) {
    if (Empty()) {
        cout << "The car doesn't have a type! Engine cannot be added!" << endl;
    }
    else {
        if (m_numEngine < 7) {
            int newSize = m_numEngine + 1;  // New size of array 
            Car* newArray = nullptr;        
            newArray = new Engine[newSize]; // Created temporary pointer to store old arrays info into temp one

            for (int i = 0; i < m_numEngine; i++) { // Storing old into new
                newArray[i] = this->engine[i];
            }
            newArray[newSize] = e;  // Adds e's values into the last index
            delete[] engine;    // Deletes old array BUT TRIGGER BREAKPOINT OCCURS HERE
            engine = newArray;  // Stores temp array back into old array so I can return "THIS" object
        }
    }

    return *this;
```

Error occurs at
"delete[] engine"

Comment: `newArray[newSize] = e;` accesses `newArray` out of bounds and invokes *undefined behavior*

Comment: One of the most horrifying things you will learn about programming is the crash site is seldom anywhere near the location of the bug. You are indeed blessed that in this case it's the line above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changed

```
newArray[newSize] = e;
```

to

```
newArray[m_numEngine++] = e;
```